# Confusion about usage of Aggregate in Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, aggregate, parse-server

So I'm trying to get my head around the aggregate function in Parse Server with no luck so far!

Here's what I'm trying to establish:

Say I have a collection named **Group**, this class contains a list of groups created by users, each record in the group contains a field which is an array of **Tag** pointers (another collection).
The _User collection also contains an array of pointers named "tags".

What I'm trying to establish, is to get the list of all the groups along with the list of users matching at least one of the tags in the tags array of the Group collection.

I'm pretty sure that this can be done with the aggregate function but I've been trying for hours with no luck!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: let's see the code you have.  If you use aggregations, then you don't get back the parse objects, just json.  Depending on what you're doing and how large the sets are, you may want to `each` over the groups and build your data structure in javascript?  That way you'll have the parseobjects for your users and groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ArthurCinader - I don't have a code, I didn't write the aggregations which is the reason why I'm posting this, I need help writing it.
Regarding the JSON response, that's not an issue actually, the issue is writing the aggregation which is confusing me :) 
Thanks!

Comment: If you give it a try and post where you get stuck it would be easier to help :).